# htaccess - rewrite to another subdir

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I read dozen of questions without getting any help so I'm sad to put another htaccess-question.

I have PDF-files:

```
www.mysite.com/default/upload/file.pdf
```

and want to rewrite them to:

```
www.mysite.com/admin/usr/default/upload/file.pdf
```

which means putting a subdir in the center of the url.

How to achieve this with htaccess dynamically?

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.pdf)$ /admin/usr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Which directory do the files actually exist in? Which is the input URL the browser sends, and which is the actual target on disk the files should be read from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!admin/usr/).+?.pdf)$ /admin/usr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Make sure this is your first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` in your root .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+\.pdf)$ /admin/usr/$1 [NC,L]
```